# The page at was loaded over https but requested an insecure xmlhttprequest endpoint

Tags: javascript, c#, https

I have an ajax request in my website to my mvc controller. All was working fine till we had installed a security connection to the site. So our site is now https. Please see below my javascript code:

```
$(".crm").click(function(){
var no_data = $("#application_user_mail").val();

    if(no_data != ''){
    }
    else{

        var Data = {
        Subject: "Test",
        CallBackType: $("#properties_form").val(),
        Article: $("#crm_flatname").val(),
        Url: $("#flat_link").val(),
        Classifierid: "7DF8DE33-EF15-E711-9431-00155D460F1A",
        };

        makeAjaxCall(Data);
    }
});

function makeAjaxCall(Data){
$.ajax({
                url: "http://.../CallBackForm",
                type: "POST", 
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(Data),
            });

}
```

In my C# code i have enable CORS to my controller

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

I'm getting the following error:

*the page at was loaded over https but requested an insecure xmlhttprequest endpoint*

How can i resolve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic mixed content error. If you load the parent page over `https` but have `http` hardcoded:

```
               url: "http://.../CallBackForm",
```

Then this will happen.

Try changing the `http` to `https` in the ajax method.

Comment: Ok, but my project(with my controller) is published in iis without ssl certificate so i cannot use https. As i understand i need to install a certificate in my iis, rigth?

Comment: You can setup IIS express to be trusted locally for development, or you can use local IIS and generate, install and trust a self-signed certificate